# Google Optimize not triggering when running on localhost

Tags: google-analytics, next.js, google-optimize

I am trying to get Google Optimize experiment data in JavaScript, by following [these instructions](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/9059383). But I get no callback and I can't see anything happening in the debugger either.

The linked instructions use the gtag way of configuring GA, so I have set up gtag according to https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/snippet, and configured Optimize according to https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/7513085?hl=en with **Method 1: Install Optimize with the global site tag (gtag.js)**.

I want to show the exact code I am using, but since I am doing it in React with Next.js Server Side Rendering, the original code has some extra stuff compared to plain HTML+JS. The source looks like this:

```
require("dotenv").config()
import React from "react"
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document"

export default class extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <html>
                <Head>
                    <script async src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID}`}/>
                    <script
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                            __html: `
                                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                                function gtag(){ dataLayer.push(arguments); }
                                gtag('js', new Date());
                                gtag('config', '${process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID}', { optimize_id: '${process.env.OPTIMIZE_ID}'});
                                console.log('GA setup done: ${process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID} + ${process.env.OPTIMIZE_ID}');
                                gtag('event', 'optimize.callback', {
                                    name: '${process.env.EXPERIMENT_ID}',
                                    callback: o => console.log(o)
                                });
                            `
                        }}
                    />
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </html>
        )
    }
}
```

This code produces a result page that starts Analytics and tracks a pageView just like it should, and when I do "RUN DIAGNOSTICS" in the Google Optimize console it opens the page, checks the JavaScript and reports:

> ### Optimize is correctly installed
>
> No major issues were detected while verifying the Optimize installation on this page.

I have also installed the Google Chrome Tag Assistant plug-in, and it reports that the Google Optimize tag is correctly installed.

I can see the following calls in the network log:

```
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxx
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
https://www.google-analytics.com/gtm/js?id=GTM-xxxxxx&t=gtag_UA_xxxx&cid=nnn.nnn
```

I have also verified that the `google_optimize` global variable is created, and it has a `.get()` method. If I look (in the debugger network panel) at the http response of the `https://www.google-analytics.com/gtm/js?...` request I can actually see the Google Optimize experiments data with the correct Experiment embedded in the code.

So everything looks good, except for the fact that the `optimize.callback` event seems to be a complete no-op. It does not do anything at all. And I don't know how else to access the experiments data that I see in the http response in the debugger.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So I finally figured out what caused my struggles: I was running from a local NodeJS server, on the usual `http://localhost:3000` url. Turns out Google Optimize will **never** trigger an experiment on `http://localhost/...` urls. The code wants a `hostname` part of the url that can be parsed according to a `host.domain` scheme.

In other words, there **must** be a dot in the hostname for Optimize to trigger an experiment.

For local testing, this can be fixed by creating a hostname alias such as `localhost.domain` for `127.0.0.1`, and accessing the web page using this alias.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, which can achieve start google optimize experiment with localhost.
So, just use next settings for google optimize experiment and it will start successfully.
[image]